# XSL Incrementing Variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I understand that XSL is a functional language, and as such variables are immutable. However that poses and issue for me.

I have a script at the moment that reads through an XML file and produces a report on all the pages that don't have a  tag. That all works fine, but I'd like to be able to return the number of XML nodes (apologies if I used the wrong terminology) that meet those conditions, any ideas how I could achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If there is an xpath expression for the elements with your condition you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(XPATH-EXPRESSION)" />
```

If not you can have a recursive template call counting on the way down. And print the value at  the end of the recursion.